# Manage server script

Tags: vbscript, inventory-management

I tried to use PStool to write some code for further server managemnt, but how can i do it within a lot servers automatically? Here is my code to handle only one server:

```
    ' list reg key value
    psexec \\<<sever name>> -u <<userName>> -p <<password>> reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl > <<server Name>>_regedit.txt
    ' list network information
    psexec \\<<sever name>> -u <<userName>> -p <<password>> ipconfig /all
    ' list services.msc
    psservice \\<<server name>> -u <<username>> -p <<password>> query > <<serverName>>_service.txt
    ' list the hotfix
    psinfo -h \\<<servername>> -u <<adminUsername>> -p <<adminPassword>> > <<serverName>>_hotfix.txt
    ' list the installed software
    psinfo -s \\<<servername>> -u <<adminUsername>> -p <<adminPassword>> > <<serverName>>_Software.txt
```

how can i add these to .vbs and execute a server list file (csv or txt) automatically?

Kindly help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the PsTools you'd use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) in VBScript. Basic example:

```
server = "hostname"

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://" & server & "/root/cimv2")
For Each obj In wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM wmi_class")
  WScript.Echo obj.property
Next
```

Replace `hostname` with the actual hostname, `wmi_class` with the name of a WMI class, and `property` with the name of an actual property of that class. Relevant classes for you are:

- [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217) (network configuration)
- [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418) (services)
- [Win32_QuickFixEngineering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394391) (hotfixes)
- [Win32_Product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378) (installed programs)

In some cases you may need to restrict the results returned by the query with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM wmi_class WHERE property = 'value'
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392902) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606) for more information about WQL queries.

You can also use WMI to [work on the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394600). In your particular scenario, you'll need the [`EnumValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390388) method to enumerate the values of the registry key, and then query the values using the respective getter method:

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002

server  = "hostname"
keyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl"

Set reg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!//" _ 
  & server & "/root/default:StdRegProv")
reg.EnumValues HKLM, keyPath, valueNames, valueTypes
For i = 0 To UBound(valueNames)
  Select Case valueTypes(i)
    Case REG_DWORD
      reg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, keyPath, valueNames(i), value
      WScript.Echo value
    Case ...
      ...
  End Select 
Next
```

Note that unlike before you're using the namespace `/root/default:StdRegProv` here.

Reading the server names from a CSV can be done using the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat) methods. For a CSV with a structure like this:

```
hostname,address,...
host_A,10.23.42.1,...
host_B,10.23.42.2,...
...
```

you'd do something like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.csv")
f.SkipLine  'skip header line
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  server = Split(f.ReadLine)(0)
  ...
Loop
f.Close
```

Note that if the CSV is in Unicode format, you'll have to change the line

```
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.csv")
```

into this:

```
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\your.csv", 1, False, True)
```